# Place icon/text on a rotating image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am using jQuery reel to display a 3D view of a site in London on my website.
[This is the example](http://rishad.me.uk/reel/TimesHouse.html).

Now I want to add some **dynamic icons and text** on 5 exact locations. I can place icons on one image like [this](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/09/02/click-image-and-get-coordinates-with-javascript/) but how can I do it for all the images so that the overlay icons and text move along with the background site images. These are about 40 images.

Can anyone please help.
Thanks

Comment: anything have you tried?

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, I can place the icon on one image. When it rotates the coordinates of that location will be different. I want to change the position according to the images. Any idea would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done it with annotations.

It is in the [documentation](https://github.com/pisi/Reel/wiki/Annotations).

```
$('#reel-image')
    .reel({
        images: 'sitePlans/<%=siteID%>/###.png',
        frames: 20,
        speed: 0,
        annotations: {
            'test':
            {
                x: [286,350,400,450,500,550,600,650,700,750,800,850,900,950],
                y: [187,150,100,150,100,150,100,150,100,150,100,150,100,150],
                link:
                {
                    text: 'This is test text', target: '_blank',
                    href:'#'
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an automatic way to do it. The animation is based on a series of images which aren't necessarily related in a specific way.

First, You would need to map the coordinates or each of the individual images.

Second, you would need to capture the event of switching the image and move the icons accordingly. I haven't seen the plugin supporting this, though I might be mistaken.

They do it in [one example](http://test.vostrel.net/jquery.reel/example/panorama-orientable-stitched/), but it looks like they're using a single image there.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, this is a panorama image and they have placed static text/links on it.